# Facebook click-id missing (fbclid)

Tags: php, facebook, get

I am currently running several ads on facebook and I have just started using the facebook-click-id to replace facebook-pixels for the tracking. For some reason I have found that there are a lot of clicks coming in through the ads without the fbclid-parameter attached to the url as a get-parameter.
Through a google search I have found out that the only reasons the fbclid-parameter would not be attached to the url would be that the user clicking on the ad is not logged in to facebook or that the user is using his/her browser with the incognito-mode activated.

It seems odd to me that so many clicks could happen under those circumstances. Which is why I am wondering if there are other reasons why the facebook-click-id (fbclid-parameter) would not be attached to the url.

Are there any other reasons why the fbclid-parameter would not be attached to the outgoing url of a facebook ad? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing some tests trying to solve the same problem, what I noticed is that fbclid parameter did not appear in outbound links when using the browser built into the mobile Facebook app.

So, I think that this is a Facebook limitation.

Hope it helps,